# Microsoft.Windows.Controls are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I'm receiving the following error:

> Error 26  The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

These two assemblies appear in the .g.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

When I remove them, the error returns.

Comment: What .net version are you targeting? Microsoft.Windows.Controls & Controls.Primitives are since .net 3.0.

Comment: These are not standard namespace names.  A minimum repro XAML snippet would normally be required to diagnose this problem.  And you'll need to check that a simple "hello world" project with just a Window compiles properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your XAML code. Probably there will be `xmlns` pointing `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives` or `Microsoft.Windows.Controls`.

Comment: Thanks i found the namespaces Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives and Microsoft.Windows.Control in a style and i removed it and it works fine .. thanks dear

Comment: Can you please share example of below one?